# Rails - Active Records - Order with a forein_key without any join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently using ActiveRecord to do my query in my rails application.

I'm actually at a point where i need to order my records but sometime this order is made with a foreign key (or in some cases with a "n +2" key - I don't really know the name).

The fact is this order is dynamic and I can't really work around all the possibilities nor use the `join`s methods (of `ActiveRecord`) because of my different relations between my tables...

Is is possible to order an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object with a foreign key without any `join`s?

Also I'll point out that so far before my `order`, in my `where`(s) I recover some foreign records but without `join`s. This is subject of change in the future, for now I try to get what I want with what I explained above.

Regards.

Comment: when you say 'without joins' are you referring to the rails method or the SQL keyword?

Comment: I'm referring to the rails method, thx for pointing that out, I'll update !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) ?

If your query uses foreign keys and you won't use joins, I can't see many other solutions...

You could try something like this:

`query = Base_Model.includes(:model_with_first_foreign_key, model_with_other_foreign_key: [:model_with_nested_foreign_key, :model_with_other_nested_foreign_key])`

After this you should be able to access any properties of all included models, as long as their relationships are correctly defined:

`result = query.order(:any_property)`

Comment: The problem with includes it's that it works just like order (I think...). But I don't know if it's that good of a pratice to include all my relation models even if my query is not using any...

Comment: You mean it works like `joins`? Obviously, as you increase the number of includes, the query is less efficient (still more than a join, if you refer to rails doc). Perhaps you could use a method `def query(*models_to_include)` and return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` so that you can still order its result?

Comment: includes does an eager load, joins does a lazy load. (edit: i hit the enter button by accident) here's a great link about it http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/

Comment: Thanks for the link, great article clarifying the pros and cons of each function (something that always eluded me)! +1